ASP.NET Core navigate on 2 different controller on exception
I need to, on exception, depending on the request (path), to redirect on the error controller for ASP.NET Core MVC or on the error controller for ASP.NET Core Web API.
In the middleware, I am trying to configure it something like this:
app.UseExceptionHandler(new ExceptionHandlerOptions
{
    ExceptionHandler = context =>
    {
        var cultureCode = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ToString();
        if (context.GetRouteData().Values.ContainsKey(RouteValueKeys.Lang))
            cultureCode = context.GetRouteValue(RouteValueKeys.Lang).ToString();

        var isApiRequest = context.Request.Path.Value.Contains("/api");

        if (isApiRequest)
        {
            context.Response.Redirect($"/{cultureCode}/api/error");
        }
        else
        {
            context.Response.Redirect($"/{cultureCode}/Common/Error/GenericError");
            app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error/Http{0}");
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
});

Then have 2 different controllers for error:
MVC:
[Area("Common")]
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<ErrorController> logger;

    public ActionResult Http404()
    {
        var context = HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
        var exception = context?.Error;

        logger.LogError(exception, exception?.Message);

        return View();
    }
}

API:
[ApiController]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
public class ApiErrorController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{lang:languageCode}/api/error")]
    public IActionResult Error()
    {
        var context = HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
        var exception = context?.Error;

        Response.StatusCode = 400;

        return BadRequest(exception.Message);
    }
}

In debug mode I can see that the value of the isApiRequest is true (I am calling it from the API), and the code runs, but it never hits the API error controller and in the browser I got 404.
Thanks

Could you share the network trace(Browser->Nerwork) to us?
